# Bash regex to match multiple blocks of indented content and print all of them

Tags: bash, parsing

I'm trying to do some regex matching in bash.
I'd like to match multiple block of indented (space or tab) content, with the block itself starting with a keyword.
Some other content could be present in the file.
Using this sample content :

```
keyword aaa match1

Some other content

keyword ccc match2
  indentend content
  matching
Some other content
  with indendation 

keyword ddd match2
  indented content still matching
```

I managed to use this : `(^keyword.*(?:\n^\h+.*)*)`, which seems to be sort of okay, everything is matching as expected. :
https://regex101.com/r/kvMlKK/1

Expected output would be to print every matches :

```
keyword aaa match1
keyword ccc match2
  indentend content
  matching
keyword ddd match2
  indented content still matching
```

Unfortunatly I did not find a way to print all matches in bash. I can use grep/sed/awk/perl without any problem (edit: i meant I have access to all these command in the environnement i am working with).

Edit:

```
grep -E --include \*.md '(^keyword.*(?:\n^\h+.*)*)' $(dirname "$0")/../_inbox/draft.md
```

Using grep it does not return the full match, only first line because of the lack of multi-line matching support I guess.
I am not familiar with awk/sed,  I did not get any meaningful results (even if it seems to be better to use them for multi-line matching).

Edit: if that could work on multiple files that would be awesome

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please update the question to show your `grep`, `sed`, `awk` and `perl` code along with the 'keywork' you're searching for; also update the question to show the expected output (for a given 'keyword')

Comment: You're regexp is not OK - it's using PCRE constructs in a a tool that's trying to parses it as an ERE. Don't assume that a regexp that works in regex101 (or any other online regexp validator) will work in any given command line tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '!/^[\t ]/{p=0} /^keyword/{p=1} p' file 
keyword aaa match1
keyword ccc match2
  indentend content
  matching
keyword ddd match2
  indented content still matching
$
```

Comment: Thanks, i went with this because of the shorter form.
I applied it to multiple files in folder like this:

`find -type f -name "*.md" -exec awk -F: '!/^[\t ]/{p=0} /^keyword/{p=1} p' {} \;`

Comment: @Pipaul adding `-F;` does nothing useful as you're not referencing any fields in the awk script and you could just use `awk '!/^[\t ]/{p=0} /^keyword/{p=1} p' *.md` instead of adding a `find` unless you have a huge number of files.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in pure bash, by looping... Because bash regex doesn't support multi-line matching.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Flag to track whether inside indented block
indented=0

# Read input line by line
while IFS= read -r line; do
  # Check if line starts with keyword
  reg="^[ \t]*keyword"
  if [[ $line =~ $reg ]]; then
    # Print line
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
    # Set flag to indicate inside indented block
    indented=1
  else
    # Check if line starts with whitespace and inside indented block
    reg="^[ \t]+.*"
    if [[ $line =~ $reg && $indented -eq 1 ]]; then
      # Print line
      printf "%s\n" "$line"
    else
      # Reset flag to indicate outside indented block
      indented=0
    fi
  fi
done < "input"
```

You can do it in `awk` too:

```
awk '/^[ \t]*keyword/{print;while(getline line) if(line~/^[ \t]+.*/) print line;else break}' input
```

Or use `sed`

```
sed -n '/^[ \t]*keyword/{:start;p;n;/^[ \t]/{p;n;b start;}}' input
```

Comment: Awk command might eat input.

Comment: @konsolebox You're right, i forgot to remove `$` lol. fixed and added `sed` syntax too.

Comment: `while(getline line)` would spin off into an infinite loop if `getline` failed, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: Regarding the shell loop - at best that'd be orders of magnitude slower than an awk script, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).